# i.i.d binary random variable question

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Suppose there are i.i.d. binary random variables $X_i \sim X$ with distribution $P(X=1) = 0.75$ and $P(X=0) = 0.25$

i) For $n=5$ and $e=0.1$, which sequences fall in the typical set $A_e^n$? What is the probability of $A_e^n$?

ii) How many elements are in the essential bit content set $S_e$ for $X^5$ for $e = 0.1$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Also, what have you tried?  What are your thoughts on the problem? Regards

Comment: i cant use mathjax because the school network does not permit the installation of software. I tried listing "00000", "00001", "00010",.... "11111" for A(e)^n but it is very exhaustive. I think that e is the error but am not sure how to find the probability. A(x) is the ensemble of {0,1}

Comment: MathJax is a markup language that you use when you edit your question. You do not need to install anything. What is $A$?

Comment: May I know how to use MathJax in edit? I am clueless about using MathJax in text, I can only see the links, attachment, headers, etc option. 'A' is the ensemble.

Comment: I've edited the question with formatting. Please take a look at it (click "edit") to see how it works (math formatting correspond to content between \$ \$ )

Comment: You forgot to define $A^n_e$.

Comment: @Did: it's the typical set of "width" $e$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typical_set

Comment: @leonbloy Thanks. Hardly canonical, is it?

Comment: @Ice: YOu don't need to list all the ocurrences, just note that the probabilities (and empirical entropies) only depend on the number of ones.

Answer (score 1):

First, compute the entropy:
$H = - \frac{1}{4} \log \frac{1}{4} - \frac{3}{4} \log \frac{3}{4} = 0.561 $ (bits/symbol)

So, $2^{-n H(X)} = 0.1431$

Now, the probability of a given 5-sequence with $k$ ones is $0.75^{k} \times 0.25^{5-k}$ Compute and tabulate this for each  $k$, and see which sequences fall in the respective $e-$typical set.

Is the above clear for you? Can you go on from here?